# Problems in running Opencv: "AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'readNet' "

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning

Using opencv for first time for object detection in an image by referring code from https://pysource.com/2019/06/27/yolo-object-detection-using-opencv-with-python/

(P.S- I am new to DeepLearning)

**Problem:**

When I run below line of code:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")
```

I get below mentioned error:

```
----> 5 net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")

AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'readNet'
```

**To Solve this:**

1) After some google on this I tried to update my opencv by using `conda update opencv-python` and also tried installing again using `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` but it remains at 3.3.1 version even after several attempts.

2) Then I learned that I need to uninstall all previous versions of opencv but I couldn't find any folder for opencv to delete just manually and `conda uninstall opencv` is running from hours now with some status `Finding shortest conflict path for python xxxxxx` and still running

3) I am thinking of manually deleting all opencv files and also able to locate opencv files but I am not sure if I should delete all of these files to reinstall opencv or not.

4) I need advice if is it safe to delete below mentioned files or not and if I delete them and reinstall opencv then should it work or not. Please Help!!

`opencv files:`

```
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_annotation.exe',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_annotation.exe.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_annotation.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_aruco331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_aruco331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_aruco331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_bgsegm331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_bgsegm331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_bgsegm331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_calib3d331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_calib3d331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_calib3d331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ccalib331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ccalib331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ccalib331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_core331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_core331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_core331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_createsamples.exe',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_createsamples.exe.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_createsamples.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_datasets331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_datasets331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_datasets331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_dnn331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_dnn331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_dnn331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_dpm331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_dpm331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_dpm331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_face331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_face331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_face331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_features2d331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_features2d331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_features2d331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ffmpeg331_64.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_flann331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_flann331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_flann331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_fuzzy331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_fuzzy331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_fuzzy331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_highgui331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_highgui331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_highgui331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_imgcodecs331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_imgcodecs331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_imgcodecs331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_imgproc331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_imgproc331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_imgproc331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_img_hash331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_img_hash331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_img_hash331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_interactive-calibration.exe',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_interactive-calibration.exe.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_interactive-calibration.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_line_descriptor331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_line_descriptor331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_line_descriptor331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ml331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ml331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ml331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_objdetect331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_objdetect331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_objdetect331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_optflow331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_optflow331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_optflow331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_phase_unwrapping331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_phase_unwrapping331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_phase_unwrapping331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_photo331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_photo331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_photo331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_plot331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_plot331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_plot331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_reg331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_reg331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_reg331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_rgbd331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_rgbd331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_rgbd331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_saliency331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_saliency331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_saliency331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_shape331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_shape331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_shape331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_stereo331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_stereo331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_stereo331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_stitching331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_stitching331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_stitching331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_structured_light331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_structured_light331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_structured_light331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_superres331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_superres331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_superres331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_surface_matching331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_surface_matching331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_surface_matching331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_text331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_text331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_text331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_tracking331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_tracking331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_tracking331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_traincascade.exe',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_traincascade.exe.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_traincascade.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_version.exe',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_version.exe.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_version.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_video331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_video331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_video331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_videoio331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_videoio331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_videoio331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_videostab331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_videostab331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_videostab331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_visualisation.exe',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_visualisation.exe.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_visualisation.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_waldboost_detector.exe',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_waldboost_detector.exe.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_waldboost_detector.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_xfeatures2d331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_xfeatures2d331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_xfeatures2d331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ximgproc331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ximgproc331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_ximgproc331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_xobjdetect331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_xobjdetect331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_xobjdetect331.pdb',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_xphoto331.dll',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_xphoto331.dll.manifest',
 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\opencv_xphoto331.pdb']
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you use Windows if so I strongly suggest you move to Ubuntu, it's free and you can install it on Virtual Machine. Here is step-by-step tutorial how to install OpenCV from sources: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/
It works fine and I never had any issue during this installation.

Comment: yes I am using windows and I am also thinking of moving to Ubuntu but first I need to solve this problem for now.

Comment: Here is how I solved these issues if anyone also faces similar problem then this may be of help:
`cv2.dnn.readNet()` needs atleast opencv 3.4.2 version to work.
1) First is downgraded my conda to 4.6 version to resolve issue "Finding shortest conflict path for python xxxxxx" as others on net also complained of same and used 4.6 version

2) Then I removed opencv 3.3.1 version and used `pip install opencv-python` to install latest opencv.